# STM32 HAL UART Interrupt unable to receive data

Tags: c, stm32, interrupt, uart, hal

I am trying to use the uart interrupt function on STM32F030xx series MCU. The initialization for uart is done using STM32cubeide, global interrupt enabled. Have already tested using HAL_UART_Transmit function and able to view the data on an UART handler software on PC. However when I try to send the data from PC to MCU, the __HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_RXNE) != RESET does not seems go to SET. The code is as follows:

```
extern unsigned char usart2_rx_buf[100];                
extern unsigned char usart2_rx_temporary[100];          
extern unsigned char usart2_rd_len;                 
extern unsigned char usart2_rd_lentemp;             
extern unsigned char usart2_rx_enableflag;              
extern unsigned char usart2_rx_checkrightflag;          
extern unsigned short usart2_executeflag;               
extern unsigned short check;                            
extern uint8_t i, j;
extern uint16_t check_temp, res;
unsigned char test_buf[3] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};

extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */
  if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_RXNE) != RESET)
      {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, test_buf, 3, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          res = (uint8_t)(huart2.Instance->RDR & 0xFF);
//...Rest of the code
```

Same as mentioned above, I tried to send the data from PC to MCU but there is no received data on my UART handler display. I am expecting the content from test_buf array.

Comment: What makes you think it is a software problem? Have you verified that you are getting an UART signal with your oscilloscope?

Comment: Do not use HAL. Implement it using CMSIS - it will be much better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tested both transmit and receive function while measure the signal using oscilloscope, can see a clear waveform. I believe the hardware is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Make sure your flow-control settings are the same on both ends. Just disabling flow-control is often the best way.

Comment: _measure the signal using oscilloscope, can see a clear waveform_ Did you measure it directly at the mcu Rx pin (if not, you still may have hardware issue, disconnect between the point you've measured and the pin)? Read out and check/post UART and relevant GPIO registers content, best after you've attempted to receive.

Comment: As you basically complaint on interrupt not working, go through the [interrupt-not-work checklist](http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g16.html), or better, write a trivial polled receiver for testing. Also note that if Rx overrun happens and is not handled properly, the receiver won't work anymore (although it would take to clear RXNE before enabling interrupts to prevent [infinitely repeated interrupts](http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g23.html)).

Comment: Totally valid comment about making sure interrupt itself is enabled and works. You can check it by manually triggering UART interrupt from software and seeing if your code jumps into the interrupt handler. Something like `NVIC->SWI = DesiredIRQNumber;` Check if UART has any flags set. One of the most common problems is the overrun flag, which is set when you didn't read the previous incoming UART byte, and another byte of data arrived. In that case, the overrun flag is set and the entire peripheral freezes until you clear the flag.